# Non-fireing if-statement

Tags: java, string, substring, indentation

How to modify this program to print just three lines and intent to 2nd and 3rd start with space. My if-statement doesn't seem work

```
package com.TnationChallange;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (String part : getParts("screen space to display information", 7, 3)) {
            System.out.println(part);
        }
    }
    private static List<String> getParts(String string, int partitionSize, int maxLine) {
        List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
        int len = string.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += partitionSize) {
            parts.add(string.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)));
            maxLine++;
            if (maxLine == 3) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return parts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter you pass to the `getParts` method is `3` and because you call `maxLine++` before `if (maxLine == 3)` that condition will never be `true`.

You should use something like this:

```
....
maxLines--;
if(maxLines == 0){
   ....
}
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a different variable to count the lines.

```
package com.TnationChallange;    
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (String part : getParts("screen space to display information", 7, 3)) {
            System.out.println(part);
        }
    }
    private static List<String> getParts(String string, int partitionSize, int maxLine) {
        List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
        int len = string.length();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += partitionSize) {
            parts.add(string.substring(i, Math.min(len, i + partitionSize)));
            count++;
            if (maxLine == count) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return parts;
    }
}
```

This is assuming you want to limit your result by maxLine.